# AngularJS variable dependent on another variable from the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code for a controller. On the initial load, the `closeBtnText` gets set properly based on the `hasClosebtn`, but when that variable gets updated later on, it doesn't get updated. Is using a method to update the only way?

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.hasClosebtn = true;
    $scope.closeBtnText = ($scope.hasClosebtn) ? "test" : 'sdffffffff';
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `$scope.$watch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to display it in the DOM, this should work:

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <p>{{ hasClosebtn ? "test" : "sdffffffff" }}</p>
<div>
```

If you need it stored in `$scope.closeBtnText`, you can use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

```
$scope.$watch('hasClosebtn', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.closeBtnText = newValue ? 'test' : 'sdffffffff';
});
```

To give some insights why that `$scope` variable does not get updated in the current code, think of this scenario:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hasClosebtn = true;
    $scope.closeBtnText = ($scope.hasClosebtn) ? 'test' : 'sdffffffff';
    // $scope.closeBtnText => 'test'

    $scope.hasClosebtn = false;
    // $scope.closeBtnText => 'test'
});
```

The flow of the code does not go back to re-evaluate your ternary expression. The detection of the change on `$scope.hasClosebtn` happens at the [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't update because your `$scope.closeBtnText` is initialized to test.

If you add and ngClick to your button that switches the value of the text you will see the change when you click it

Since it is a newcomer's to angular question i am gonna give you the doc link for ngClick for further investigation [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)